# How to get view from Activator?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I create new plugin of viewPart

I have class myView

```
public class myView extends ViewPart {
   public static String ID =....
  }
```

I want to find the view from the Activator.java

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
```

I tried

```
IViewPart findView = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(myView.ID);
```

but i didn't get any result

I tried also

```
IViewReference findViewReference = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
     .findViewReference(myView.ID);
```

then I got result but I didn't know how to get the class.

Comment: Is this myView.ID specified the ID of the view as declared in the plugin.xml file ?

Comment: where i can find it in the plugin.xml ?

Comment: does it under view id ?

Comment: yes it is the same ID

Answer (score 1):

`findView` and `findViewReference` only return the view if it is currently visible on the page.

Use `IWorkbenchPage.showView` to show a view. This only requires the view id string.

Comment: I just want instance of the class to move it to other class it is possible with showview

Comment: What do you mean by 'move it to other class'?

Comment: I meant that I want to get the class myView (somehow ) and to move it to new class as one of the parameters

Comment: Eclipse only constructs the view class when it is about to show the view. `showView` returns the view class that was created.

Comment: does shiwView will return the class myView ?

Comment: Yes it returns the class you declare in the plugin.xml

Comment: I tried to do it in the Activator and I got dump null exception maybe I can't to it from the Activator in the start method